# Creating table views with columns from nested value of a jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in one of the tables that has the following structure:

```
{
  "3424": {
    "status": "pending",
    "remarks": "sample here"
  },
  "6436": {
    "status": "new",
    "remarks": "sample here"
  },,
  "9768": {
    "status": "cancelled",
    "remarks": null,
    "by": "customer"
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a view that will put the statuses in individual columns and the key will be their value:

```
pending | new  | cancelled | accepted | id | transaction
3424    | 6436 | 9768      | null     | 1  | testing
```

The problem is the key is dynamic (numeric and corresponds to some id) so I cannot pinpoint the exact key to use the functions/operations stated here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

I've read about `json_path_query` and was able to extract the statuses here without the need to know the key but I cannot combine it with the integer key yet.

```
select mt.id, mt.transaction, hstatus from mytable mt
cross join lateral jsonb_path_query(mt.hist, '$.**.status') hstatus
where mt.id = <id>
```

but this returns the statuses as rows for now. I'm pretty noob with (postgre)sql so I've only gotten this far.

Comment: What if you have two entries with `pending`? Or three with `cancelled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a PATH query. Unfortunately it's not possible to access the "parent" inside a jsonpath in Postgres. But you can workaround that, by expanding the whole value to a list of key/values so that id value you have, can be accessed through `.key`

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value.status == "pending").key') #>> '{}' as pending,
       jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value.status == "new").key') #>> '{}' as new,
       jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value.status == "cancelled").key') #>> '{}' as cancelled,
       jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value.status == "accepted").key') #>> '{}' as accepted,
       id, 
       "transaction"
from the_table
```

The jsonpath function `$.keyvalue()` returns something like this:

```json
{"id": 0, "key": "3424", "value": {"status": "pending", "remarks": "sample here"}}
```

This is then used to pick the an element through a condition on `@.value.status` and the accessor `.key` then returns the corresponding key value (e.g. 3424)

The `#>> '{}'` is a hack to convert the returned `jsonb` value into a proper  `text` value (otherwise the result would be e.g. `"3424"` instead of just `3424`.